# whenever I upgrade my helm chart all my previous configrations are lost

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kube-prometheus-stack

I have deployed Prometheus and Grafana with the help of Helm using kube-Prometheus-stack on the Kubernetes cluster to monitor the Kubernetes cluster. After installing kube-prometheus-stack to the grafana dashboard and some configuration files, I have done some changes. Now when I want to do changes to values.yaml and upgrade the helm chart all my previous configuration is lost and all object of kube-Prometheus-stack are again deployed what should I do

I am expecting after upgrading the helm chart using values.yaml my previous configuration should remain same data shouldn't be lost